# Https requests with Authorization not working via Safari

Tags: angularjs, https, safari, asp.net-core

**Context**

XHR requests with Authorization header over HTTPS (both together) don't reach the server, using Safari (IOS and MacOS). But it works with IE, Chrome and Firefox.

I use a valid certificate generated by Letsencrypt and browsers don't display warnings about it.

On the web inspector of Safari, these XHRs try to get result until timeout and no errors displayed.

I have one domain and no sub-domain.

**Test**

- Authorization header + HTTPS => Not working
- Authorization header + No HTTPS (HTTP) => Works
- No authorization header + HTTPS => Works

**Code**

I use an interceptor to set authorization header.

```
this.request = (config) => {
    config.headers = config.headers || {};
    var authData = localStorageService.get('authorizationData');
    if (authData && config.url && !config.url.endsWith("/token")) {
        config.headers = {
            "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + authData.access_token
        };
        config.withCredentials = true;
    }
    return config;
}
```

Has anyone encountered the same problems ?

**UPDATE 1**

There is something wrong with Safari + HTTPS + "Authorization" header.
If I rename "Authorization" by "MyHeader", and doing some modification on server to retrieve my bearer token with "MyHeader" token, everything works well.

Is "Authorization" header a protected word using HTTPS on safari ?

Comment: Did you ever determine if Authorization was a protected word on Safari?

Comment: I didn't find anything about protected words on Safari.

Comment: We discovered what the issue was for us. If you attempt to use Safari on an insecure certificate (self-signed was the culprit for us), then Safari does not allow you to manipulate the Authorization header field.

Our solution was to either trust the self-signed cert or to switch to normal http (both solutions worked). Sounds to me that your issue was different, though

Comment: We have the same bug, but strangely, using the same signed wildcard certificate on 2 different machines, one is not working. We have no clue what's happening. certificate : *.companyname.com: server1.companyname.com = working, server2.companyname.com = not working. On firefox, chrome, IE works perfectly. On safari not working except an iPAD with version 8, but all latest iPhones and iPad,Mac, the request doesn't arrive at the server. If we change the 'Authorization' header, it works (partially, because we need the authorization header). Could anyone help how to debug, test, ...?

Comment: @NicolasLaw-Dune how did you solve this ? currently facing this isse, i cant put a '/'  the end of all requests, did changing Authorization to something else solve the issue ? or did it bring any other issues after changing it , coz i think Authorization is a universaly recognised word for sending tokens

Answer (score 42):

I also faced a similar problem with safari where 'Authorization' in the header was not sent in the GET request but it ended up in a simple thing.

I simply appended a '/' at the end of the request URL and it worked for me.

for eg: change URL from '/token' to '/token/'.

Comment: seems like iOS dont send request headers on redirection

Comment: @nilay jha what about urls with params ?

Answer (score 2):

To solve that you need access to the device that are running the code and change a safari setting that prevent cross-site tracking, this works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

When an HTTP request made via safari is made to any url contains words like `login`, `token`, etc... safari automatically adds `Accept-Encoding` header that brokes al

Answer (score 0):

In my case, using Laravel, it was just the slash removed by .htaccess. When there is an redirect, by obvious reasons, the headers not are forwarded.