# How to get JWT bearer token from WebAPI with Safari as the client?

Tags: ios, asp.net-web-api, safari, jwt

**Overview**

I have a WebApi 2.0 project that uses JWT tokens to protect endpoints. When a user logs in to my web application, an AJAX request is made to the API, which generates and returns a bearer token to the user, which is then saved in sessionStorage client side so that requests to protected end points can be made.

Note that both my web application and API are hosted over https, using CORS.

**The problem**

This all works fine when using Firefox, Chrome, Internet Explorer and Edge. However, when I log in to my web application through my iPhone or iPad, the API does even get called and therefore no token is returned. Meaning that my web application cannot get data from protected endpoints, which in effect makes it a bit useless!

**Research**

[Https requests with Authorization not working via Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35684933/https-requests-with-authorization-not-working-via-safari)

It looks like the user in the question above is at least getting a token back from the server, which is more than I am getting at the moment.

Does anyone have any insight into why this could be happening?

**Update 05/01/2017**

Just to make this question and answer more accurate. This wasn't a problem with bearer token generation or consumption, simply that Safari wouldn't actually make an AJAX request to my API without setting async: false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After pulling my hair out all day I finally came up with a solution.

For anyone else that is having this issue, the way I fixed it was by adding async: false to my request, like this:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: apiBase + 'OAuth/Token',
        data: loginData,
        async: false // Adding this fixed my issue.
    }).done(function (data) {
        sessionStorage.setItem("tokenKey", d.access_token);
    });
```

Comment: Did you remove async in both the request and the generate token function?